# How to retrieve elements ordered by position instead of DOM order in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm using jQuery Draggable to re-arrange the certain DOM elements. Now I would like to retrieve those elements ordered by current position instead of DOM order.

Currently jQuery selection returns the elements in DOM order.

How to retrieve the elements sorted by current position using jQuery?

Comment: Do you need vertical position or horizontal?

Answer (score 0):

if you want physical position on page you will have to write a custom function that returns the x,y co-ordinates on the page.

I would suggest getting all items by their y coordinate (distance from top of page) and then ordering by x co-ordinates if they have same position from top.

[.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) is best for this.

Add all dom elements to an array then sort by position as above.

**NOTE** - this will be a LOT of heavy lifting for jQuery - bare that in mind - if certain elements are the ones you want to re-order I would suggest manually assigning id's and running whatever logic dictates layout on them instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a function for the vertical order of the elements. You can also make this horizontal by checking the left property of the elements.

Try this

```
$(function() {
    function SortByTop(a, b){
      var top1 = a.top;
      var top2 = b.top; 
      return ((top1 < top2) ? -1 : ((top1 > top2) ? 1 : 0));
    }

    var order = [];
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
        stop: function(event,ui){
           var dr = $('.draggable');
            order=[];
            dr.each(function(ind,val){
                var obj = $(this).position();
                obj.id = $(this).attr('id');
                order.push(obj);
            });
            order.sort(SortByTop);
            for(var i=0;i<order.length;i++){
                console.log(order[i].id)
            }

        }
    });
  });
```

See demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LvcPB/)